# Jquery-Mobile Cordova Geolocation-Find users around you feature

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am wondering if any of you could help me to find a tutorial, course or book to implement a geolocation for my project where you can find other users according to your location (Tider and Meetup style).

I have a project which is base on JQuery Mobile, Cordova and getting data from MySql using PHP and Ajax call. Even though I have google it for hours I cannot find any usable source of information that guide me to implement this feature on my project.

I have the Cordova geolocation installed and working fine, so it give me the `getCurrentPosition`but how to implement the "find users around you" feature?

Any link, course, info will be very appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=calculate%20distance%20between%20two%20coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds more like a question about php and mysql than about cordova or jquery-mobile: once you have obtain the location, you need to send a request to your server, it will return you a list of people near you.
If you have a lot of users, you may want to use geospacial indexing; which is not a core feature of mysql, but [some extensions exist](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html).